# Collection.findOne() does not return any results in Template.created

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have a template which is a simple edit form. The `_id` of the document to be edited comes in a session variable (set by `mini-pages` from the URL: `http://example.com/items/4zt4z3t3t`). In the `Template.editForm.created`function I try to get the correponding document from the collection using `ItemCollection.findOne({_id:_id})`. The `_id` is set correctly in all cases.

When I navigate to `http://example.com/4zt4z3t3t` and debug the `created` function, `ItemCollection.findOne()`returns undefined, although there are items in the collection. Therefore I can never find my item by _id. Also, when I move the item find procedure to the routing stage, there is also no result for the find. Later on, the colleciton works as expected.

Any pointers?

Comment: I did some more analysis: when I call the URL directly (not via Meteor.go), `mini-pages` seems to call the page two times. The first time the Collection is not defined. Seems to be an issue with `mini-pages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor uses a [Data on the wire](http://docs.meteor.com/#sevenprinciples) principle. This means when your HTML has loaded your data isn't sent along with it, at least initially.

You can't therefore access data in a `.created` function, unless you expect that template to be loaded after the data has been downloaded. This is why it returns `undefined` initially but if you check later its there.

You can either, wait for a callback from the subscription on when the data is completed, then load the template.

OR

Use reactivity in your template and let it load empty, and automatically fill it up with data when the data has come in (really the easiest). Access your data in the template and use a handlebars helper to fill in the data and use the `.rendered` callback to do any changes after.

Comment: I went for the second solution and used a helper which does the findOne when it's actually needed in the template.

Still, when I load the URL I get a quick flicker with an empty form, then the form with the data. I think this is an issue with mini-pages loading the page two times.